# Function pointer declaration works in C but not in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

So i am currently importing a small C library into a new empty C++ project, but it simply won't compile. It works just fine compiling it with C, but it simply doesn't with C++. The only thing i am doing is including the header.

It seems to be a syntax fault, but it could be someting else. This is the only thing the compiler nags about:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before 'export'
bool (*export)(struct wld_exporter * exporter, struct wld_buffer * buffer, uint32_t type, union wld_object * object);
error: expected ')' before 'export'
```

Since i thought it was a syntax issue, i just didn't know what to do and tried stupid things like moving the asterix after export instead of prior hoping that it would work, but it obviously didn't.

I have no idea why the compiler can't recognize that it's supposed to be a function pointer, i have done function pointers c-style in c++ before without any issues.

I am using gcc and C++11 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`export` is a keyword in C++. You'll have to choose a different name.

Comment: Oh i see. It's even highlighted in both my editor and here on stackoverflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`export` is a keyword in C++, you can't use it as an identifier.

List of keywords here: [C++ keywords](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword)